# nginx-proxy returns 503 error over http and https

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, docker

I'm setting up [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) as a reverse proxy in front of Docker container running an app server. They're defined in separate Docker compose definitions. For some reason I'm getting a `503`, but I don't know why and I've gone over the `nginx-proxy` docs in detail.

(I've also opened this [as a github issue](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/426) for `nginx-proxy`.)

The app server originally served https over `443` with `10443` exposed on the host. I switched to serving http over `80` with `10443` exposed on the host.

I can curl from the app server directly, but curling through nginx-proxy throws up an error

I initially had nginx-proxy on `443`, but I switched it to `80` for now.

Until I added `default.crt` and `default.key`, I was getting a connection refused error. After adding them, I'm getting a `503`.

```
curl http://foo.example.com:80/apidocs --verbose --insecure
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 10.x.x.x...
* Connected to foo.example.com (10.x.x.x) port 80 (#0)
> GET /apidocs HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: foo.example.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
* Server nginx/1.9.12 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/1.9.12
< Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 17:26:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 213
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.12</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host foo.example.com left intact
```

Here's my compose definition for nginx-proxy. I'm using `network_mode: bridge` which is [supposed to work](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/304) even with `version: 2`.

```
version: '2'
# Not yet compatible with custom networks in v2 of Compose
services:
  nginx:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    # Necessary until nginx-proxy fully supports Compose v2 networking
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro"
      - "nginx-log:/var/log/nginx"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
volumes:
  certs:
    external: true
  nginx-log:
    external: true
```

Here's my app server composition:

```
version: '2'
services:
  database:
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.4-13
    restart: always
    # Necessary until nginx-proxy fully supports Compose v2 networking
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "55433:5432"
    environment:
      - DB_USER=foo
      - DB_PASS=...
      - DB_NAME=foo_staging
      - USERMAP_UID=1000
    volumes:
      - "foo-data:/var/lib/postgresql"

  foo:
    image: private-registry.example.com/dswb/foo:1.4.3
    restart: always
    container_name: "dswb-foo"
    links:
      - "database:database"
    # Necessary until nginx-proxy fully supports Compose v2 networking
    network_mode: bridge
    ports:
      - "10443:80"
    volumes:
      - "certs:/home/rails/webapp/certs"
    environment:
#      - "CERT_NAME=example.com"
      - "VIRTUAL_HOSTNAME=foo.example.com"
      - "VIRTUAL_PORT=80"
      - "VIRTUAL_PROTO=http"
    command: "bash -c 'rake db:migrate && thin --port 80 --address 0.0.0.0 start'"
volumes:
  foo-data:
    driver: local
  certs:
    external: true
```

The certs are less relevant since I switched to port `80` to debug. I have a wildcard certificate for `*.example.com`. I made a copy named `foo.example.com` in case nginx-proxy couldn't find it. I tried both setting and not setting  `CERT_NAME`. I've now also generated the `dhparam` stuff.

```
root@8b02a7deb220:/etc/nginx/certs# ls -la
total 48
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 21 18:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr 21 18:06 ..
-rw------- 1 root root 3575 Apr 21 18:03 example.com.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  769 Apr 21 18:03 example.com.dhparam.pem
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Apr 21 18:03 example.com.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1838 Apr 21 18:03 default.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3268 Apr 21 18:03 default.key
-rw------- 1 root root 3575 Apr 21 17:37 foo.example.com.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  769 Apr 21 18:15 foo.example.com.dhparam.pem
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Apr 21 17:37 foo.example.com.key
```

This is the only thing that shows up in the nginx-proxy log when I curl:

```
nginx.1    | foo.example.com 10.x.x.x - - [21/Apr/2016:17:26:16 +0000] "GET /apidocs HTTP/1.1" 503 213 "-" "curl/7.35.0"
```

Nothing shows up in app server log, meaning it does not see the request.

How do I debug this? Are there better logs somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with setting your nginx log to debug and then check to see where the request throws the 503

```
server {
    #other config
    error_log    /var/logs/nginx/example.com.error.log debug;
    #other config
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say port 80 to 10443, is your Docker install still serving HTTPS?  If so, try to set both to HTTP and use a less confusing port 10080 on Docker.

Comment: No, I switched the service to http (and verified that it was http via curl).